# Does Json.NET offer an instance API?

Tags: .net, json, json.net

Does Json.NET offer an instance API besides the static `JsonConvert` API, in a similar fashion to how AutoMapper lets you have mapper instances, each with different configurations?

My scenario: I need different serialization settings for the same classes when calling from different services. I want to avoid, if possible, passing serializer settings on every call from every service. I would like to have "Serializer" (probably not the exactly right word) instances injected into my services, each with its own configuration. Is this possible with Json.NET?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, of course.  [`JsonConvert`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert.htm) is just a facade to make it easier to do common tasks with [`JsonSerializer`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer.htm).  You can create different instances of `JsonSerializer` and use them independently if you want.  All of the settings in the [`JsonSerializerSettings`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings.htm) class are also on the `JsonSerializer` itself.  Have a look at the [source code](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonConvert.cs) if you want to see how `JsonConvert` wraps `JsonSerializer` and transfers settings to it.

Note that the `JsonSerializer` class deals with [`JsonReader`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonReader.htm) and [`JsonWriter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonWriter.htm); it does not have the same easy-to-use methods to work directly with objects and strings that `JsonConvert` has.  However, it is very easy to make some simple extension methods to do the same thing if that is what you need:

```
public static class JsonSerializerExtensions
{
    public static string SerializeObject(this JsonSerializer serializer, object obj)
    {
        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        using (JsonTextWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, obj);
            return sw.ToString();
        }
    }

    public static T DeserializeObject<T>(this JsonSerializer serializer, string json)
    {
        using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(json))
        using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
        {
            return serializer.Deserialize<T>(reader);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
JsonSerializer ser = new JsonSerializer { Formatting = Formatting.Indented };

Foo foo = new Foo();
string json = ser.SerializeObject(foo);

foo = ser.DeserializeObject<Foo>(json);
```

Comment: Does this mean that I need to give up the nice `SerializeObject(Object)` and `DeserializeObject<T>(String)` syntax? If so, that's a bummer as I need to start worrying about also maintaining Readers and Writers, correct? I'm not saying the answer is not what I'm looking for, I would just want to have that clarified before marking as accepted.

Comment: While it is true that the `JsonSerializer` class does not have overloads that work directly on objects and strings like the `JsonConvert` class has, that doesn't mean you have to give up the nicer syntax.  Just make a couple of extension methods and you'll be good to go.  I've updated my answer with this info.